# read slide layout, slide mode and spellcheck

Tags: python-pptx

I am developing a python script which requires me to check whether the slide layout is properly used... I see a function called '**follow_master_background**', this gives me a boolean answer 'true or false'. However, I need to get the name of the layout used which will help me to validate whether they chose a proper layout. Is there a way?

Also, do we have an option in python-pptx to check the slide mode (fit mode) and what type of spellcheck used in the ppt.

Let me know if there are options for these.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is two questions. You should reduce it to one and ask the second one separately. I'll respond to the first question.

Comment: It did work... Thank you Scanny for your response. I will post the second questions separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code provides access to the name of the slide-layout used by each slide in the presentation:

```
prs = Presentation("my-pptx.pptx")

for slide in prs.slides:
    layout = slide.slide_layout
    print(layout.name)
```